# View activity history of a question

Tags: feature-request, old-questions

Is it possible to add a history view to a question, one that lists all edits (including delete actions if delete contents cannot be displayed), comments, answers in a list, sorted on datetime?

Take this question: [KeePassHttp refuses to be recognised as a plugin](https://superuser.com/questions/317790/keepasshttp-refuses-to-be-recognised-as-a-plugin)

I see it was "active" today, but I can't find what activity. I see this quite often, a question that is old, but I don't notice that, I open it, start to answer it, then suddenly see it's from 2011 and no activity since one or two years. I think this is a waste of time, as the asker will probably have found a solution one way or the other.

Answer (score 8):

There is a timeline, which you can access using the following URL:

```
http://sitename/posts/<question_ID>/timeline
```

And a way to go to the latest activity is to add `/?lastactivity` to the URL, like this:

```
http://sitename/questions/<question_ID>/title/?lastactivity
```

But the timeline says that the latest activity is on Nov 15 '13, <s>it's very likely that there was an answer posted that's now deleted.</s> (Community♦ bumped it, see Doorknob's answer).

Answer (score 4):

Notice how it appears on the front page:

[image: screenshot]

It was bumped by the [Community♦](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) bot because it didn't have any upvoted answers. From the bot's profile description:

> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

This means that answering the question is by no means "a waste of time." Since there aren't any satisfactory answers yet, adding your own will help future readers get the answers they need.

For the record, though, if you click the timestamp next to the "activity" marker in the sidebar:

[image: clicky]

you will be redirected to the specific post (question or answer) in which the activity happened.